# ResourceBundle as PropertySource in spring

Tags: java, spring

The PropertySource [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) demonstrates the use of `@PropertySource` to inject property file key/value pairs into the spring context.

I want to know if it is possible to do the same with resource bundles. For example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration")
public class FooBar {
    @Value("${my.key}")
    private String someValue;

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("my.key = " + someValue); 
    }
}
```

*configuration.properties*

```
my.key=foo
```

*configuration_en.properties*

```
my.key=baz
```

the result of printMe on an instance of FooBar would print the string:

```
my.key = baz
```

If the `user.language` system property was set to `en`

Comment: yes you can do the same where internationalization is required.

Comment: So i got it right in the question?

Comment: `@Value`s are processed during startup not at run-/execution time. So no you cannot load a locale sensitive properties file. If you want to you would have to use a `MessageSource` and manually retrieve the value each time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try annotate your message source with @Resource

```
    @Resource(name = "<id of your configured message source>")
    protected MessageSource resources;

    public void printMe() {
            System.out.println(resources.getMessage("my.key", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); 
    }
```